Reference on Stirling's Approximation?
I am reading this link here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Higher_orders and saw this:

I was just wondering - are there any official references for this form?

Did you look at the references at the bottom of the page? there I see several sources mentioning Stirling.

Abramowitz and Stegun  . Chapter 6  is on the Gamma function.

This is page 262 from the fifth edition of Whittaker and Watson, A Course of Modern Analysis

